# Overloading operator<< - must be a binary operator

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, overloading, friend

What's the error here? I reviewed prior Q&A, but all those coders appear to have made other errors when overloading <<. When I try it, QT Creator gives this error: `overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)`, referring to the line in the `.h` file.

Edited code below...

**domino.h**:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class domino {

public:
    domino();
    domino(int leftDots, int rightDots);
    std::string toString() const;
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const domino & dom);
private:
    int leftDots;                           /* Dots on left side */
    int rightDots;                          /* Dots on right side */
};
#endif
```

**domino.cpp:**

```
#include "domino.h"
#include <string>
domino::domino() {
    this->leftDots = 0;
    this->rightDots = 0;
}
domino::domino(int leftNum, int rightNum) {
    this->leftDots = leftNum;
    this->rightDots = rightNum;
}
std::string domino::toString() const {
    return "[ " + std::to_string(leftDots) + "|" + std::to_string(rightDots) + " ]";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const domino & dom) {
    return os << dom.toString();
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "domino.h"
#include "domino.cpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    domino dom;
    std::cout << dom << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for(int j = i; j < 7; j++) {
            domino newDom(i,j);
            std::cout << newDom << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The operator should be declared either as a friend function of the class

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const domino & dom);
```

or you should remove the operator declaration from the class definition.

Otherwise the compiler considers the operator as a member function of the class.